# translating text in lua file

Tags: replace, lua

The thing is, I'm translating a game from English to Polish language. The text I'm trying to translate is in lua-files. I have most of the game translated, but I'm looking for a way to automatize replacing English text with Polish text.
I have a few lua-files (which are very large), which contain code and text to translate, I have `.txt` files which contain sentences line-by-line in English language, which I want to have replaced in lua-files and I have same amount of other txt-files which contain sentences line-by-line (in the same order) in Polish language. I need help with a script which will take first line from `english.txt`, search for it in lua and, if found, replace it with first line from `polish.txt`, and then take 2nd line from `english.txt`, etc.
I tried many applications, but none of them had this function. Someone advised me to use `awk`, `grep` or `sed`, but I didn't find out how to use them for my purpose.

EDIT: Sorry. I forgot that the old files were .lua. Now it is .sjson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may think it is too much work, but there are existing methodologies for handling *internationalization* in programs, such as **gettext**, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) and [GNU website](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/index.html). Basically, tools are used to extract the strings from the program's source code, collecting them in a file. Someone translates these to provide a new language, then the program is modified slightly so that at run time the correct language file is chosen depending on the user's `LANG` setting.

Though originally done for the C programming language, it is now available for several others, including [lua](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Lua.html) according to the GNU website.

To see how it works in C, here's a short but complete [tutorial](https://www.labri.fr/perso/fleury/posts/programming/a-quick-gettext-tutorial.html).

Comment: Oh, I forgot.... Sorry... Old files of the game were .lua. Now it is .sjson, and as I found out using poedit and searching on the internet, gettext doesn't support .sjson.